# julia error: method too new to be called from this world context

Tags: function, module, julia

I want to execute the function of the module (denoted daughter) by executing another module (denoted mother).
To do that, I wrote down code as follows in the mother:

```
include("User/initialization/Background.jl")
initialization.Background() #1
```

However, the daughter didn't work because of the following error:

MethodError: no method matching Background()
The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 32734, while current world is 32738.
Closest candidates are:
Background() at C:\Windows\Application Data\User\initialization\Background.jl:7 (method too new to be called from this world context.)

#### Edit

I now have added the details of my code:

```
module Hi
using DelimitedFiles
function Hi_Hello()
if Command[1,1]==1
include("User/initialization/Background.jl")
initialization.Background() #1 
else
end
end
end
using .Hi
Hi.Hi_Hello
```

and

```
module initialization
using Plots, DelimitedFiles, BSplineKit
function Background()
writedlm("Background.txt", data_BG)
end
end 
using .initialization
initialization.Background
```

It is executing using VScode and initialization(module) included in the directory:("User/initialization).

when I command on the terminal, it works.
include("User/initialization/Background.jl")
initialization.Background() #1

but when I command through executing function, it didn't with error as I mentioned original post.
*MethodError: no method matching Background() The applicable method may be too new: running in world age 32734, while current world is 32738. Closest candidates are: Background() at C:\Windows\Application Data\User\initialization\Background.jl:7 (method too new to be called from this world context.)*

Answer (score 2):

While your question does not provide enough information to identify the root of the problem (most likely it is related to some macros generating your function's code), the solution is most likely to invoke the latest version of your function. So it seems this will help (BTW module names are recommended to be started with Capital Letters):

```
@invokelatest initialization.Background()
```

#### Edit

After you updated the question now I can see the problem.

You should put the `include` statement *before* the function `Hi_Hello()`  *not inside it*.
Normally when programming in Julia you do not want functions to dynamically include, load  and recompile modules (and hence your error).